Ubuntu 20.04 BT mouse primary button no longer work
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.  Since the last automatic update my BT mouse does not work properly.  I have the same problem with several different BT mice I have tried.
The primary button (in my case the left one) no longer selects.  When pressed, the button calls up the exact same information that the right button does.
I have not made any changes to any settings that may have caused an issue.  I can only say that after the last automatic update and re-start the next day the BT mouse no longer worked properly.
A corded USB mouse and the touch screen mouse on my laptop both work properly.  That is why I think it is a BT issue.
